# Changing an image with a delay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

for the past couple of hours I was trying to change an image in Xcode with a delay. I have tried achieving this using the following code:

```
UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 2, options: [], animations: {
    self.TapTap_intro.image = UIImage(named: "Second TapTap")
}, completion: nil)}
```

The problem while using this code is that it appears to not respect the delay and change the image immediately.

Could anyone please explain me what am I doing wrong and how could I possibly fix this issue?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Do you want the new image to "slide in and push the other image out"? Do you want it to "cross-fade"? Do you want it to "fade-out the current image and fade-in the new one"?

Comment: @DonMag Just want it to replace the old image without an animation.

Comment: The `image` property of `UIImageView` is not a view animatable property.

Answer (score 1):

To make a change without animation , there is no need to use `UIView.animate` You can dispatch it after some delay

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2 ) {
     self.TapTap_intro.image = UIImage(named: "Second TapTap")
 }
```

Comment: Where you put the code ??? also try to use UIView.animate not UIImageView.animate

Comment: I've put tried putting the code in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad but both yield the same result. I also tried using UIView.animate instead of UIImageView.animate but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: try it in viewDidAppear , fact is that delay time in action when you still not seeing the view

Answer (score 1):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
    // Do your thing         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer instead of animate:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

And create a function to change the image:

```
func changeImage() {
   self.TapTap_intro.image = UIImage(named: "Second TapTap")
}
```